# VBScript passing parameter to JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, vbscript, parameters

I am attempting to populate a button dynamically using VBScript and call a JavaScript function from it passing a parameter (I'd like to pass 2).  Here's what I have:

```
WriteLn ("<td nowrap class=""ContentActionSmall"">
<input type='button' name='VeiwReport' value='VIEW REPORT' 
onclick='jsfunction()'> </td>"
```

This is a static call to the jsfunction:

```
function jsfunction(lnk)
{
    alert("fx called V0.4 "+lnk);
    go_pop_upA("/aa/rpt/detailedReport_go.asp");
}
```

This part also works.  But it is static.  I need to pass a variable inside the `onclick='jsfunction()`  like this:

```
WriteLn ("<td nowrap class=""ContentActionSmall"">
<input type='button' name='VeiwReport' value='VIEW REPORT' 
onclick='jsfunction(TOPIC_ID)'> </td>"
```

When I do this, `jsfunction` does not execute.

I've tried a number of things, including calling a VBScript Function or sub with the VB functions and subs not executing (calling jsfunction)

The goal is to open another page with the TOPID_ID and another string passed to the new page, which will be a popup window the user can close.  So the above code, which was mostly in place when I started, does not have to remain the same.

Comment: Why you are using Writeln() to create td element?

Comment: I'm doing code maintenance, and that is what was there already.Is there a better way?

Comment: The variable you want to pass is in the HTML document?

Comment: It comes from a table: For intI = 0 To UBound(arrData,2)

    Course_ID = arrData(0,intI)
    Course_Name = arrData(1,intI)
    TOPIC_ID = arrData(2,intI)

Comment: Ok, when you loop your array, where did you put  TOPIC_ID ?

Comment: For intI = 0 To UBound(arrData,2)

    TOPIC_ID = arrData(2,intI)

Comment: the I try to pull it in the line above:    WriteLn ("<td nowrap class=""ContentActionSmall"">
<input type='button' name='VeiwReport' value='VIEW REPORT' 
onclick='jsfunction(TOPIC_ID)'> </td>"

Comment: Try to put this WriteLn ("<td nowrap class=""ContentActionSmall""> <input type='button' id='& TOPIC_ID &' name='VeiwReport' value='VIEW REPORT' onclick='jsfunction(this.id)'  concat the TOPIC_ID result in attr id

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was... too complex a way to approach this.  So I ditched the input/button and went back to this:

```
Response.Write("<td nowrap class=""ContentActionSmall"">
<a href=""javascript:go_pop_up('/aa/rpt/detailedReport_go.asp?
TOPIC_ID="& TOPIC_ID &"')"">View Report</a>")
```

This worked.

Comment: Don't use `< a href="javascript:...">...</a>` it's doesn't degrade nicely! See [Href attribute for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/135120/692942), it's a throwback from an earlier time and shouldn't be anywhere in modern code.

Comment: Also [javascript:; vs javascript:void(0);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125685/692942)